# All possible values of a complex integral

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, analysis, curves, residue-calculus

I'm struggling with the following task:

Find all possible values of the complex integral $\int_0^1 \frac{dz}{z^2 + 1}$ if we are integrating it along all possible curves from $0$ to $1$.

The official answer is $\frac{\pi}{4} + k\pi, k \in \mathbb{Z}$. I understand that if we integrate it along the line from $0$ to $1$, we get the answer $\frac{\pi}{4}$, but I don't understand how do we get all other possible values of the integral, so help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you calculated the residues of the integrand?

Comment: What are the values of $$2\pi i\mathop{\mathrm{Res}}_{z=i}\frac{1}{z^2+1}\qquad\text{and}\qquad 2\pi i\mathop{\mathrm{Res}}_{z=-i}\frac{1}{z^2+1} \qquad ?$$ And how are these related to the integral $\int_{\gamma} \frac{\mathrm{d}z}{z^2+1}$ for any path $\gamma$ from $0$ to $1$ that does not pass through $\pm i$?

Comment: @SangchulLee The values are $\pm \pi$, but I don't know how the residue is connected to the path as the curve is not neccessarily closed. Should I maybe make it closed by adding a line between 0 and 1 to it?

Comment: That is a good point, and indeed considering the closed path $\gamma \cup [1, 0]$ (path $\gamma$ followed by the line segment from $1$ to $0$) will do the job: $$\int_{\gamma}\frac{\mathrm{d}z}{z^2+1} = \underbrace{\int_{\gamma\cup[1,0]}\frac{\mathrm{d}z}{z^2+1}}_{\text{over closed path}} + \underbrace{\int_{[0,1]}\frac{\mathrm{d}z}{z^2+1}}_{=\pi/4}. $$

Comment: Integrate from $0$ to $1$ along a straight line as before.  But in the middle of that line, take a detour using a closed curve surrounding $i$.  What is the value of the integral along the path from 0 to 1 including the detour?

Comment: @SangchulLee I don't understand how the value of the integral along the closed path can be any multiple of $\pm \pi$. By the residue theorem, the integral is a sum of residues at singularities which are contained in the region bounded by the closed path. But there are at most two singularities in that region. So I understand that $\pm \pi$ or $0$ can be the value of the integral along the closed curve, but I don't understand why $\pm k\pi$ can be the values of that integral for any integer $k$.

Comment: A (not necessarily simply) closed curve can wind a given point any integer multiple of times ($+1$ for each round of CCW winding and $-1$ for each round of CW winding), leading to the notion of [winding number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winding_number). Then this winding number enters the (generalized) Cauchy integral formula. To give a sense of this, consider the following toy example: Let $\gamma(t) = a + r e^{kit}$, $0\leq t\leq2\pi$ and $k\in\mathbb{Z}$, be the curve winding $a$ $k$ times. Then try to compute $$\int_{\gamma}\frac{\mathrm{d}z}{z - a}$$

Comment: @SangchulLee I understand now, thank you very much! We only stated the residue theorem for simply closed curves in our lectures, so I didn't know about this generalization. Thank you very much again! I would accept your answer if I could do so in the comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To enlighten the solution, let me first state the [residue formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem):

> **Proposition.** Let $f$ be holomorphic on $U \setminus \{a_1, \ldots, a_n\}$, where $U$ is a simply connected doamin and $a_1, \ldots, a_n$ are distinct. Then for any closed curve $\gamma$ in $U$,
>
> $$ \int_{\gamma} f(z) \, \mathrm{d}z = 2\pi i \sum_{k=1}^{n} \operatorname{Ind}_{\gamma}(z_k) \mathop{\mathrm{Res}}_{z = a_k} f(z), \tag{1} $$
>
> where $\operatorname{Ind}_{\gamma}(z_k)$ is the [winding number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winding_number) of $a_k$ with respect to $\gamma$ defined by
>
> $$ \operatorname{Ind}_{\gamma}(z_k) = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{\gamma} \frac{\mathrm{d}z}{z - a_k} \in \mathbb{Z}. $$

Although the proof of the general statement requires some work, this hints how we may proceed in OP's case, assuming we know that winding numbers are always integers.

Indeed, let $\gamma$ be any contour from $0$ to $1$ that does not pass through $\pm i$. Also, let $\tilde{\gamma} = \gamma \cup [1, 0]$ denote the contour obtained by by appending the line segment from $1$ to $0$ to $\gamma$. Then

\begin{align*}
\int_{\gamma} \frac{\mathrm{d}z}{z^2+1}
&= \int_{\tilde{\gamma}}\frac{\mathrm{d}z}{z^2+1} + \int_{[0,1]}\frac{\mathrm{d}z}{z^2+1} \\
&= \frac{1}{2i} \int_{\tilde{\gamma}}\frac{\mathrm{d}z}{z - i} - \frac{1}{2i} \int_{\tilde{\gamma}}\frac{\mathrm{d}z}{z + i} + \frac{\pi}{4} \tag{by partial fractions} \\
&= \pi \operatorname{Ind}_{\tilde{\gamma}}(i) - \pi \operatorname{Ind}_{\tilde{\gamma}}(-i) + \frac{\pi}{4}.
\end{align*}

Since $\operatorname{Ind}_{\tilde{\gamma}}(i)$ and $\operatorname{Ind}_{\tilde{\gamma}}(-i)$ can assume any integer values, it follows that $\int_{\gamma} \frac{\mathrm{d}z}{z^2+1}$ can assume any values of the form $ k\pi + \frac{\pi}{4}$ for any $k \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Thank you for your help!